# About the data update timing of the current_timestamp type column

Tags: mysql

When I published a UPDATE sentence in MySQL5.1, update is inapplicable, and the column of a certain current_timestamp type is updated by time when I carried out UPDATE.
Will it be the data column which is updated even if current_timestamp type may not lack in UPDATE explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created the table you can setup the first TIMESTAMP column with both DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP clauses, the column has the current timestamp for its default value, and is automatically updated.

You can find more information on timestamp here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html

Matt